# Boost Hypergeometrict test

Tags: c++, r

I am trying to perform the hypergeometric test in C++ as an exercise, but have been getting different answers in R every time.  My question is am I using an int somewhere which causes truncating of the pdf or am I just doing the test improperly.

**My example problem:** Suppose I have 100 marbles, and 8 of them are red. I draw 30 marbles, and I want to know what's the probability that at least five of the marbles are red?

```
    #include <boost\math\distributions\hypergeometric.hpp>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <boost\math\policies\policy.hpp>
    #include <iostream>  


/*
    *Description:  Perform hyper geometric test on value.
    * Paramater val1: is r defective"sucess"
    * Parameter val2: is N-r total objects in population - success
    * Parameter val3: is Number of objects.
    * Paramater val4: Is K number of events
    */
    void hypergeometrictest(int n1_val, int n2_val, int n3_val, int n4_val)
    {
        double pdf, cdf;
        unsigned int n1 = n1_val;
        unsigned int n2 = n2_val;
        unsigned int t = n3_val;
        unsigned int k = n4_val;
        printf("These are values: %i, %i, %i, %i \n", n1, n2, t, k);

        // hg_dist(r,n,N)
        //r = success
        //n = 
        boost::math::hypergeometric_distribution<double> hg_dist(n1, t, n1 + n2);
        pdf = boost::math::pdf<double>(hg_dist, k);
        cdf = boost::math::cdf<double>(hg_dist, k);

        std::cout << "This is my PDF: " << pdf << std::endl;
        std::cout << "This is my CDF: " << cdf << std::endl;

    }

    int main() {

        hypergeometrictest(8, 92, 30, 5 );

        //working on windows PC but remove if on Unix
        system("pause");
        return 0;

    }
```

when I run the function I get a different pdf/p-value:

```
This is my cdf: 0.991497
This is my pdf: 0.0419199
```

In R the I performed the same hypergeometric test to check and got a different number:

```
   phyper(4, 8, 92, 30, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.05042297
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Trying to grasp the Problem**

The first problem is that what you implemented in C++ is equivalent to <kbd>[**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/LMN4581)</kbd>

```
phyper(4, 8, 92, 30, lower.tail=TRUE)
```

which outputs

```
[1] 0.949577
```

This flag means that you assume the following

> lower.tail: logical; if TRUE (default), probabilities are P[X≤x], otherwise, P[X>x].

For further reference on that see [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/Hypergeometric).

The second issue with this is, that you used different numbers, i.e. `hypergeometrictest(8, 92, 30, 5 )` instead of `hypergeometrictest(8, 92, 30, 4 )`.

**Solution**

So to fix this, you have to take the complement to 1. in order to compute CDF and use the correct numbers

```
cdf = 1. - boost::math::cdf<double>(hg_dist, k);
```

And you get `This is my CDF: 0.050423` (which is by the way the corret answer). This holds as obviously `1 - phyper(..., lower.tail = TRUE)` is the same as `phyper(..., lower.tail = FALSE)`

Comment: Very nice breakdown and contains a lot of information

Comment: Wow @P i I was stumped on this for a while. This is so clear.